# manipulating jLabel from main method in netbeans

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to change the text inside a jLabel from the main method, the reason for this is because there are conditions that I need to meet for the change to happen and it is not trigger based.

**Code:**

```
public class TheMain extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public TheMain() {
        initComponents();
    }

public void changeLabel1(){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               jLabel1.setText("looo");
            }
        });
    }

    public void changeLabel2(){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               jLabel2.setText("looo");
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         TheMain some = new TheMain();
         if(condition){
             some.changeLabel1();
         }else{
             some.changeLabel2();
         }
    }

}
```

I tried printing some stuff inside `changelabel1` and `changelabel2` just to check if they are successfully called and it did print but I'm guessing it is not possible to implement the UI changes inside them, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     if(condition){
         some.changeLabel1();
     }else{
         some.changeLabel2();
     }
```

The above logice needs to be defined in TheMain class because that is where the label variables will be defined.

The main() method is just used to create the GUI. There should be no application logic in the main() method.

Comment: i thought it is in the main() function that application logic should be placed, like before i used the main to print hello world

Comment: You are not talking about a simple "hello world" example that shows how to compile/execute a class. You are asking about creating a GUI. Look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for demo code you can download an execute. It will show you how to better structure your code.

Comment: @makingitwork How are jLabel1 and jLabel2 created? A common cause for this kind of problem is declaring them as instance variables and then hiding them with a local variable when they are created: `JLabel label1 = new JLabel():` instead of `label1 = new JLable();`